# Rebuilding ggplot plot from gtable does not respect theme()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to manipulate an element of a ggplot object. To do this, I convert it into a gtable using `ggplot_gtable` and `ggplot_build`, make the change using `grid::editGrob`, then rebuild back into a ggplot using  the `cowplot` functions `ggdraw` and `draw_grob`. This works well, except for when I want to change the resulting plot with `theme()`. `theme()` has no effect on the new plot.

For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

data(iris)

p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + geom_point()
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
p2 <- ggdraw() + draw_grob(gt)

# theme() works correctly
p1 + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

```
# theme() is ignored
p2 + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

How can I use `theme` with the edited ggplot?

Comment: The `gt` variable in your code has the theme baked in already. `p2` is not the same as a ggplot object. You cannot change theme elements afterwards, except for manually editing the grid graphical objects.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to try a different approach!